# Enumerate list and print the index and selected values of dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following example code:

```
contact_book = []

contact = {'Name:': 'Foo', 'Surname:': 'Bars', 'Adress:': 'Foostreet, 3',
           'Number:': '123456'}
contact2 = {'Name:': 'Boo', 'Surname:': 'Bark', 'Adress:': 'Boostreet, 31',
           'Number:': '6554321'}
contact3 = {'Name:': 'Coo', 'Surname:': 'Barf', 'Adress:': 'Coostreet, 32',
            'Number:': '999999'}

contact_book.append(contact)
contact_book.append(contact2)
contact_book.append(contact3)

print(list(enumerate(contact_book)))
```

the output is:

```
[(0, {'Name:': 'Foo', 'Surname:': 'Bars', 'Adress:': 'Foostreet, 3', 'Number:': '123456'}), (1, {'Name:': 'Boo', 'Surname:': 'Bark', 'Adress:': 'Boostreet, 31', 'Number:': '6554321'}), (2, {'Name:': 'Coo', 'Surname:': 'Barf', 'Adress:': 'Coostreet, 32', 'Number:': '999999'})]
```

I want to output only with the index position of the contact and then the values of the keys `'Name'` and `'Surname'`.

```
[(0, {'Name:': 'Foo', 'Surname:': 'Bars',}), (1, {'Name:': 'Boo', 'Surname:': 'Bark'}), (2, {'Name:': 'Coo', 'Surname:': 'Barf'})]
```

How can I access only the `Name` and the `Surname` value, additionally with the index position of the contact? I tried it with list enumerate, but I'm open too for other approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build dicts containing only the required keys in a list comprehension, generating the corresponding indices in the comprehension using `enumerate` like so:

```
keys = ('Name', 'Surname')
lst = [(i, {k: d[k] for k in keys}) for i, d in enumerate(contact_book)]
```

Comment: `{k: d[k] for k in keys}` can be replaced with `get_keys(d)` where `get_keys = operator.itemgetter(keys)`

Answer (score 0):

One can loop through each contact and get values as follows:

```
outlist = [] 
counter =0
for onedict in contact_book:
    oneitem = []
    oneitem.append(counter)
    oneitem.append( {"Name:":contact["Name:"], "Surname:":contact["Surname:"]} ) 
    outlist.append(oneitem)
    counter += 1

print(outlist)
```

Output:

```
[[0, {'Surname:': 'Bars', 'Name:': 'Foo'}], [1, {'Surname:': 'Bars', 'Name:': 'Foo'}], [2, {'Surname:': 'Bars', 'Name:': 'Foo'}]]
```